# Trouble connecting to DB in .NET Core app while following tutorial

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, database-connection

Ok, here's my issue. I'm following the tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

And when I get to the section where you first test the app, I get a connection error for my database. I haven't touched the connection string (the tutorial doesn't say to). But the error I get is this (through the console):

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>         Failed executing DbCommand (76ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
>         CREATE DATABASE [SchoolContext-ce3ad5d4-bcc1-45d9-a13f-50c3b2624a6f];
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\SchoolContext-ce3ad5d4-bcc1-45d9-a13f-50c3b2624a6f.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>   ClientConnectionId:2aa20854-bffb-4fcb-b736-4d1669245bf5
>   Error Number:5123,State:1,Class:16
>   fail: MY_PROJECT.Program[0]
>         An error occurred creating the DB.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\SchoolContext-ce3ad5d4-bcc1-45d9-a13f-50c3b2624a6f.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Create()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
>      at MY_PROJECT.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\\source\repos\MY_PROJECT\MY_PROJECT\Program.cs:line 23
>   ClientConnectionId:2aa20854-bffb-4fcb-b736-4d1669245bf5
>   Error Number:5123,State:1,Class:16

So it's not even *creating* the database.

What could the issue be? I've Googled a few things, but nothing really seems to answer this specific question. Do I need to set permissions on the "my_username" folder in order for this to work?

Comment: You're trying to write directly to `C:\Users`, where you don't have write access. Your access starts at `C:\Users\YourOwnUserName` or `C:\Users\Public`. You have to change the connection string to point to a location where your account has permissions to write files before the DB can be created there.

Comment: Ok, here's my connection string:

Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SchoolContext-ce3ad5d4-bcc1-45d9-a13f-50c3b2624a6f;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

What do I need to add to do that?

Comment: First off, try running Visual Studio as Administrator and run it again. I don't expect that to work, but it's worth a shot. Most likely, the account that's running the Sql Server process doesn't have permissions to create a file in your user directory. You can change that configuration in Sql Server. https://techyaz.com/sql-server/change-database-default-locations-sql-server/

Comment: Tried that. I'm still completely lost as to where to change it. Tried your link also. No dice there, either.

Answer (score 3):

for me it was that => my ***appsettings.json*** and ***appsettings.Developement.json*** files not having the same connectionstring ... so go to both files and make sure they are containing the same databaseName.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I discovered the answer to this question.

Apparently, it's not a flaw in .NET or .NET Core. It's a SQL Server local DB issue. If you're running SQL 2017 (as I am) you have to install the latest cumulative update. that will fix the issue.

As of this time, the most recent cumulative update is this one: Cumulative Update Package 19 for SQL Server 2017 - KB4535007

Which I got from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128

Comment: Could you update the answer to include more details to help people coming across this question to know which "cumulative update" you are referring to? The "latest cumulative update" probably won't stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new maigration.
in package manager console.